Getting attributes from a tag type that is passed as a string
How can I get a list of attributes (any /Type?/) from a tag that was passed as a string.
export const createElement = (Component: ElementType) => {
    return ({...props }: any /*Type?*/) => (
        <Component
            {...props}
        />
    );
};
const Some = () => {
    const Textarea = createElement("textarea");
    const Input = createElement("input");

    return (
        <>
            <Textarea placeholder={"123"} type={"color"}/> {/*type={"color"} must be error*/}
            <Input type={"color"} />
        </>
    )
}

I need that when I pass attributes they correspond to the tag that was passed

The key points here:

JSX.IntrinsicElements is a special type that maps the names of the HTML elements to their properties type
An explicit call to React.createElement() -- or whatever the equivalent is, if your target is not React -- is necessary to create an element from its name as a string, rather than a component function

Therefore, your createElement could look something like this:
import React from 'react';

export const createElement = <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>(elementName: T) => {
    return (props: JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]) => React.createElement(elementName, props);
};

